# Problem with JSON formatting when using a location column

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, view-formatting

I want to create a view using JSON formatting. In this view I want to use a location column called "Adres" (I checked the URL and the field name really is called "Adres").

The formatting works fine with all the other columns, except when I try to add the value from the location column. In the formatting I type `[$Adres]`, similar to the other columns, but the whole view disappears. As long as I don't use location columns the formatting works fine.

Do I have to refer to the value of a location column in a certain way other than `[$Adres]`?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is the data type of your column? Location?

Comment: Hi Ganesh, the column is indeed a location type colum. With all the other types of column everything works fine.

Comment: Can you please add a JSON code you are using to your question? it will be helpful to answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use Location fields you need to use one of the properties it exposes in JSON formatting.

The location field object has the following properties (with example values):

```
{
   "Address": {
      "City": "Knoxville",
      "CountryOrRegion": "United States",
      "State": "TN",
      "Street": "963 Worlds Fair Park Dr"
   },
   "Coordinates": {
      "Latitude": "35.961673736572266",
      "Longitude": "-83.92420959472656"
   },
   "DisplayName": "World's Fair Park",
   "LocationUri": "https://www.bingapis.com/api/v6/localentities/8346bf26-6da4-104c-6ba5-2334b83f6ac8?setLang=en"
}
```

For Example, if you want to get the name of City then you need to use `[$InternalName.Address.City]` OR if you want to get the name of country or region then you will use `[$InternalName.Address.CountryOrRegion]`.

So, make sure you are using this column in proper supported format/syntax.

**Reference**: [Use column formatting to customize SharePoint - Special String Values](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting#special-string-values)

Comment: Thank you Ganesh. Problem solved! I used [$Adres.Address.Street] instead of [$Adres]

Comment: Great, glad it helped you.